# strtotime('today') returning incorrect time?

Tags: php, unix, time, strtotime, timezone-offset

I am trying to create a select list starting from the current date of the user. I want it so that it is set to midnight in unix timestamp format.

This is all I'm doing:

```
$today = strtotime('today');
echo $today;
```

This is my result:

```
1333144800
```

which is: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 22:00:00 GMT according to Epoch Converter (incorrect by a couple hours.)

Comment: Looks like the server's timezone is set to GMT+2, so you're actually getting the correct result.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want strtotime() to return a timestamp relative to UTC (00:00:00 UTC instead of e.g. 00:00:00 UTC+2, if your system is set to a timezone with an offset of 2 hours against UTC/GMT), you need to specify that:

```
$today = strtotime('today UTC');
```

Answer (score 6):

**GMT (+0) time**

```
echo $today = strtotime('today GMT');
echo "<br>" . $today = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $today);
```

We expect that your server runs at GMT - that is the best (for maneuvering with time displays later). If not, you MUST adjust php.ini set this "date.timezone = GMT".

When you get that done, you will see 00:00 with my codes.

Then, you must develop function (ie DisplayDate()) in your script to display dates of your website correctly if

- youre not in GMT area
- or/and if you want for your users to see times in their timezone with timezone selection for example.

DisplayDate() should include support for daylight changes also (0, or +1 hour / summer and winter time).

Answer (score 3):

```
strtotime( $time )
```

is designed to return a unix timetamp, meaning, it will return the number of seconds since jan 1, 1970. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

To get around this, use something like:

```
$today = date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime('today'));
echo $today;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to specifically set the time as well as the day:

```
$today_midnight = strtotime('today UTC 00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the timezone configuration in your php.ini file. In my case (I live in El Salvador) I had to change it like this:

```
date.timezone = America/El_Salvador
```