# strtotime not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, web-scraping, strtotime

So Im scraping a website for data, and one piece of data that im scraping is the date of certain items.

The date of the items comes in the format "Wed 11th March, 2015".

I have been trying to then insert this into my mysql database. The structure of the database contains a column with "datapublished" as a Timestamp,

```
`feeddatapublished` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

When updating the rest of the columns with the data it updates fine with the following code

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `feedsdata` (`id`, `feedid`, `feedurl`, `feedsummary`, `feedtitle`, `feeddatapublished`) VALUES (NULL, :feed_id, :feed_url, :feed_summary, :title, :datapublished)");

$stmt->bindParam(':feed_id', $feed_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':feed_url', $feed_url);
$stmt->bindParam(':feed_summary', $feed_summary);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $feed_title);
$stmt->bindParam(':datapublished',$datepublished);
$stmt->execute();
```

I converted the string from the feed before passing it to be inserted with

```
$datepublished = strtotime(scrape_between($separate_result, "<span class=\"date\">", "</span>"));
```

scrape_between is a function I use for the scraping.

When echoing out the $datepublished I get the timestamp 1458155700, which isnt the correct timestamp from what i can see.

All other columns are updating as required, the only one which isnt is the datepublished one.

My two questions are

1. Is the reason its not updating because im passing a malformed timestamp to the mysql database
2. How can I generate a better timestamp from the format above, Ive checked the date function but I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Are you sure that your `scrape_between()`  function is working correctly and giving the correct results ?

Comment: Additionally, are you getting any php and/or MySQL errors. Do you have error reporting turned on for your code ?

Comment: It is giving me the correct results. Ive echoed them out and checked them, its the conversion into a timestamp which isnt working. error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1); are set  and nothing coming through

Comment: Could this be the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957616/why-does-my-strtotimetoday-not-work ?

Comment: I've already set the locale, but ive reset it in the php to check. An example is this...

Tue 24th November, 2015 with strtotime comes out with 1480450500

Is it because of whitespace in the scraped data maybe?

Comment: If I try `strtotime("Wed 11th March 2015")` then I am getting correct result (without the comma). Do you wanna try that and see if that works ?

Comment: echo  strtotime("Wed 11th March 2015");
returns 1426028400
which is the 10th March

Comment: I am getting `1426046400` in PHPFiddle which gives me back 11th March 2015. http://phpfiddle.org/. May have something to do with timezones but looks like you are closer to it now than before.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL `timestamp` format is `2016-02-13 15:48:29`   or `Y-m-d H:i:s`  convert your `unix timestamp` to that format first, and then MySQL will accept it.

Either with

```
<?php

$datapublished = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(scrape_between($separate_result, "<span class=\"date\">", "</span>")));
```

OR

your query to

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `feedsdata` (`id`, `feedid`, `feedurl`, `feedsummary`, `feedtitle`, `feeddatapublished`) 
                        VALUES (NULL, :feed_id, :feed_url, :feed_summary, :title, from_unixtime(:datapublished))");
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks! Didnt realise mysql has a different format!

Comment: no worries, Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.  welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the date format used on the webpage you're scraping and it stays constant, you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for safer and more controlled date parsing.

```
<?php
$datestring = "Wed 11th March, 2015";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("D dS F, Y", $datestring);

// Reset hours, minutes and seconds - otherwise the current time is used
$date->setTime(0, 0, 0);

// Format for MySQL database insertion
$datepublished = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `strtotime` is not smart enough to recognise the string so its best guess is 1458155700.

you can add an additional step to clean the date:

```
$scrape = scrape_between(...);
$cleanDate = preg_replace(
    '/[a-z]+ ([0-9]{1,2})[a-z]+ ([a-z]+), ([0-9]{4})/i',
    '$1 $2 $3',
    $scrape
);
$datepublished = strtotime($cleanDate);
```

the `preg_replace` function uses a regular expression to remove the unnecessary parts.